# Trying to import cell data based on cell drop down

Tags: excel, import

I'm trying to re-do a spreadsheet.. Without having to put an =if into every cell where the data would be variable depending on the selection of a drop down (Which is how it is set currently :( )

On the main sheet.. Cell J1 i have a dropdown selection.. And im looking for the cells in
A1-F1 to be populated with the information on the data sheet.. Based on the selection either 1 or 2 in this example but i cant figure out how to do this

Any help would be appreciated

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is what VLOOKUP functions are for. VLOOKUP functions search for a key in the first column of a range, and matches the selected row on it.

You can just put `=J1` into your A1 cell, and on your B1 cell you can search for A1 as `=VLOOKUP($A1,Data!$A$1:$F$2,2,FALSE)`. This formula can be read like this:

"Please, search for the value that it's in `$A1` in table `Data!$A$1:$F$2`.When you got it, get me the column `2`. Ah, by the way, if you asked me if the key column is made of sorted numbers, so if you can't find it, you can extrapolate linearly, I'd answer `FALSE`, got it? Thanks a bunch!"

So, in your C1 cell you'd ask for the column `3`, and so on. Of course, if you'd like to just create a single formula, you can insert a row over your row 1, and put the column references over the cells, as this:

[image: Same workbook he provided with 2,3,4,5,6 on cells B1:F1]

In this case, my formula on B1 is `=VLOOKUP($A2,Data!$A$1:$F$2,B1,FALSE)` - which can be dragged to C1:F1. Of course you can later hide the row 1 from your user.

Hope that helps.